# How to add an image to list items in Html?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following html code for a simple menu:

```
<div class="wHeader">
        <div class="header">
        <img src="header.png">
        </div><!-- header ends here -->
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="current-item">Home</li>
           <li>
                <a href="#">Language</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href=#>Lang1</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Lang2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other ...</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>  <!-- menu-wrap ends here-->
```

The CSS style for `<ul>` is as follows:

```
.sub-menu {
    width:120%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    background:#808080;
}
```

I'm trying to put a flag image in one of the list items like this:

```
<li style="list-style-image: url('smallflag.png');"><a href=#">Lang1</a></li>
```

But so far the image is not appearing. Is there any conflict with background? Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Why do you have a top 100% and opacity set to 0. Both these properties are making the li hidden or out of view. You property is just fine and will work without the opacity:0 and top:100%. Just make sure the url is correct and that the image exists in that url.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sub-menu {
width:120%;
padding:5px 0px;
position:absolute;
/*top:100%;*/
<!--left:0px;-->
z-index:-1;
/*opacity:0;*/
transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
background:#808080;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wHeader">
     <div class="header">
      <!--<img src="header.png">-->
     </div><!-- header ends here -->
    <div class="menu-wrap">
     <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="clearfix">
       <li class="current-item">Home</li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Language</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href=#>Lang1</a></li>
           <li><a href=#>Lang2</a></li>
           <li style="list-style-image: url('http://placehold.it/20x20');"><a href="#">Other ...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
```

The sub-menu class is hiding it and moving it to the bottom of the screen, also the picture is lost with the left:0px property.

If you comment out the top:100%, left:0 and opacity properties, the item will show with its image